# There is a short way to write if(!is_null($foo) && !is_null($bar))?

Tags: php

So, I am writing a function that receives two arguments, and before I do anything with these variables, I want to check if they are not null.

```
if (!is_null($foo) && !is_null($bar)) {
    /* do something */
}
```

The problem is that I think we are repeating code, and in some cases when the variable name is a little bit bigger, it becomes painful to write every time.

So, there is a way to shorten this code?

Comment: You're not putting every individual statement in a seperate `if` block, right?

Comment: There isn't really a shorter way to check if a variable is turly `NULL`.

Comment: Where do you think the repeating code coming from? From your example you only need that 1 if statement to check if both are not null? What else are you wanting?

Comment: the only way would be to define a function which does this stuff - would look like `myCheckFunction(myValuesArray)`

Comment: try `if(count(array_filter(func_get_args()))==func_num_args()){ }`, can be used in all functions

Comment: I just want to know if there is a way to avoid writing `!is_null` for each argument i want to check. If it is the only way, i'll be ok with that, but i want confirm with you guys.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, works not only for `NULL` also for `` and `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `isset` which returns FALSE if variable is null. You can set there a lot of variables so code will be shorter:

```
if (isset($foo, $bar))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own function to check this:

```
function is_any_null() {
    $params = func_get_args();
    foreach($params as $param) {
        if (is_null($param))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
if (!is_any_null($foo, $bar)) {
    /* do something */
}
```

Comment: Interesting approuch.

Answer (score 0):

`is_null()` checks a variable to determine if the value is `NULL`. It can be used in an `if statement`. It depends on what you would like to do in that `if statement`. For example, if you would like to do an `echo`, you can make it a bit shorter using the `elvis``operator:

```
echo (is_null($foo) && is_null($bar)) ?: 'The values are not null';
```

Or you could make it a one liner by leaving the `{` and `}` out of your code and putting everything on one line.

```
if (!is_null($foo) && !is_null($bar)) die("NULLLLL");
```